# I was installing parlance ctcdecode and got this error

Tags: python

I was installing parlance ctcdecode in windows 10 with python version 3.7.9 and pytorch version 1.10.0+cpu
**PLEASE HELP!**

```
setup.py:37: UserWarning: File `third_party/kenlm/setup.py` does not appear to be present. Did you forget `git submodule update`?
  warnings.warn("File `{}` does not appear to be present. Did you forget `git submodule update`?".format(file))
setup.py:37: UserWarning: File `third_party/ThreadPool/ThreadPool.h` does not appear to be present. Did you forget `git submodule update`?
  warnings.warn("File `{}` does not appear to be present. Did you forget `git submodule update`?".format(file))
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\tanmay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\extension.py:131: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'package', 'with_cuda'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Comment: are you on windows? you seem to be trying to install a linux version

Comment: yeah, I looked at the github repo and this wont compile on windows, but some users reported it working using ubuntu via [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)

Comment: That library seems to be _not_ designed to be installed on Windows, as indicated by the [open Github issues about Windows](https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+windows), by its [setup.py file using `bash` and Linux paths](https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode/blob/master/setup.py#L41-L52), and by the note in the README that it needs to compile with gcc and clang.

Comment: Please suggest me what should I do to install ctcdecode on windows.

Comment: you can't. it only works on linux. you will need to either get a linux machine or run a virtual machine (like the WSL2 i mentioned earlier)

Comment: Ok Thank You for your Help